# How to create links relative to the right context?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, navigation

I have this composition :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"> 


    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{empty userc.userb.user.id}">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" >
            <h:outputLink value="system/register.xhtml">Register</h:outputLink>
            <h:outputLink value="system/login.xhtml">Login</h:outputLink>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:panelGroup>

</ui:composition>
```

If the user click in `Login`    the page is redirect to `system/login.xhtml`, which is correct, but if the user, click in `Login` again, it is redirect to `system/system/login.xhtml`.
I know a solution for this, which BalusC help me out a long time ago:

```
<base href="#{fn:replace(request.requestURL, fn:substring(request.requestURI, 1, fn:length(request.requestURI)), request.contextPath)}/" />
```

It solve my problem, but if I have some ManageBean instancied when I click in some link the bean it's invalidate.

How mantain the url path in every link page and keep the session in the Managed beans ?

Comment: I posted an answer, but just curious, I do not understand your problem that the bean is "invalidated". What exactly happens? Is the session really invalidated and recreated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`<h:link>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/link.html) instead. JSF will append the right context path and `FacesServlet` mapping.

```
<h:link value="Register" outcome="/system/register" />
<h:link value="Login" outcome="/system/login" />
```

#### See also:

- [Communication in JSF 2.0 - Implicit navigation](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ImplicitNavigation)

Comment: Great my friend! Thanks! =]
Just one observation, how my .xhtml was not in the same folder, I should put one slash before, just like this :
<h:link value="Login" outcome="/system/login" />

Thanks!